# sql - Is there a way to filter through the results of a SELECT query, with another SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-order-by, where-clause

Specifically, what I am trying to do is rank a table by a column value, referred here as `power`, and then take that ranked table and find a specific row, or a user in this case. Much like what would be done in a video game leaderboard to find the ranking of a specific user.

Basically, I would like to find a specific row in a table that has been ordered. I know how to do both, but not together.

I guess what I'm trying to do is combine these statements:

Sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY power DESC;
```

Filtering:

```
SELECT * FROM otherQueryResult WHERE discordID = discordIDInput;
```

And then find out the row number of the row that is returned.

Realistically, I'd like to have a result that looks something like this:

```
+-----------+------+
| discordID | rank |
+-----------+------+
| 123456789 |  52  |
+-----------+------+
```

Being 14, my SQL knowledge is still very limited - so I would prefer simpler solutions over raw performance or usability at the moment, however any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you give the column names because in order to achieve your taget you have to do a join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a window function such as `RANK()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT u.*, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY power DESC) rnk FROM users u) x 
WHERE discordID = ?
```

The inner query assigns a rank to each user, with the user having the highest `power` ranked first. Then, the outer query filters the user that has the relevant `discordID`.

There are other window functions that can respond to your use case:

- `ROW_NUMBER()`: assigns a rank to each record ; even-records are not treated consistently
- `RANK()`: even-records get the same rank ; if two users have rank 1, then the following user has rank 3
- `DENSE_RANK()`: same as `RANK()`, but does not create gaps in the ranks

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables and then rank.
`select discordid, RANK() OVER

    (PARTITION BY u.userid ORDER BY (the column that you are ranking from) DESC) AS Rank from otherqueryresult as q inner join user as u on u.id=q.userid`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the calculation directly.

I think you want:

```
select 1 + count(*)
from users u
where u.power > (select u2.power from users u2 where u2.discordID = ?);
```

You do not actually need window functions for this purpose.  With indexes on `(discordId, power)` and `(power)` this should have very very good performance.